# How can I generate json to excel file?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have serious difficulties converting my Json data to excel sheet. I tried lots of ways like pandas but I think its not working because of my json data structure.I have lots of nested data so its become complicated. Here my sample data for converting to xlsx. How can I convert it? Please help me.
Here data for converting excel sheet :

```
{

 "orders" : {
"kullanicilar" : {
  "aWNNmb52ivNkw2UTzstFK0l2v5F3" : {
    "-LtiyfykM1Km3EnG9LE2" : {
      "Bluz" : 1,
      "adres" : {
        "siparis alinma adresi" : "19 Mayıs - Erenköy Ruh ve Sinir Hastalıkları Hastanesi Yolu - Keke - Kadıköy - Msmsns - Msms - 29.088680323689218 - 40.975330066587176",
        "siparis edilme adresi" : "19 Mayıs - Erenköy Ruh ve Sinir Hastalıkları Hastanesi Yolu - Keke - Kadıköy - Msmsns - Msms - 29.088680323689218 - 40.975330066587176"
      },
      "isim" : {
        "username" : "Zımbırtı"
      },
      "tarih" : {
        "teslim alinma tarihi" : {
          "alinma saati" : "18:00 - 19:00",
          "alinma tarihi" : "17/11/2019"
        },
        "teslim edilme tarihi" : {
          "alinma tarihi" : "22/11/2019",
          "teslim saati" : "10:00 - 11:00"
        }
      },
      "toplam tutar" : {
        "toplam paket tutari" : 44.8
      },
      "urun adetleri" : {
        "adetler" : [ 1, 1 ]
      },
      "İpek bluz" : 1
    },
  "svxebbcGymRd1ubZtiuA12qixHi1" : {
    "-Lt0SimxXsB9dGwcmmWk" : {
      "Pantolon" : 9,
      "adres" : {
        "siparis alinma adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185",
        "siparis edilme adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185"
      },
      "isim" : {
        "username" : "Batuhan dinç"
      },
      "tarih" : {
        "teslim alinma tarihi" : {
          "alinma saati" : "",
          "alinma tarihi" : "07/11/2019"
        },
        "teslim edilme tarihi" : {
          "alinma tarihi" : "14/11/2019",
          "teslim saati" : "18:00 - 19:00"
        }
      },
      "toplam tutar" : {
        "toplam paket tutari" : 146.20000000000002
      },
      "urun adetleri" : {
        "adetler" : [ 9 ]
      }
    },
    "-Lt5AAAcwt0EEe0rIgIH" : {
      "Bluz" : 6,
      "adres" : {
        "siparis alinma adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185",
        "siparis edilme adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185"
      },
      "isim" : {
        "username" : "Batuhan dinç"
      },
      "tarih" : {
        "teslim alinma tarihi" : {
          "alinma saati" : "18:00 - 19:00",
          "alinma tarihi" : "08/11/2019"
        },
        "teslim edilme tarihi" : {
          "alinma tarihi" : "13/11/2019",
          "teslim saati" : "10:00 - 11:00"
        }
      },
      "toplam tutar" : {
        "toplam paket tutari" : 134.3
      },
      "urun adetleri" : {
        "adetler" : [ 1, 6 ]
      },
      "İpek bluz" : 1
    },
    "-Lt6D-5NNq9wjhl_KRvB" : {
      "Bluz" : 1,
      "adres" : {
        "siparis alinma adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185",
        "siparis edilme adresi" : "Eğitim - Azra Sokak - Mahsun no:5 - Kadıköy - 8 - 37 - 29.04100730120266 - 40.992459475638185"
      },
      "isim" : {
        "username" : "Batuhan dinç"
      },
      "tarih" : {
        "teslim alinma tarihi" : {
          "alinma saati" : "",
          "alinma tarihi" : ""
        },
        "teslim edilme tarihi" : {
          "alinma tarihi" : "09/11/2019",
          "teslim saati" : "18:00 - 19:00"
        }
      },
      "toplam tutar" : {
        "toplam paket tutari" : 44.8
      },
      "urun adetleri" : {
        "adetler" : [ 1, 1 ]
      },
      "İpek bluz" : 1
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried this https://pypi.org/project/tablib/0.9.3/ ?

Comment: @prhmma I already tried tablib too.

Comment: so please include your desired results and maybe some codes that you have already tried

Comment: What you've pasted is missing a `}` at the end to be valid.  Is that a typo?  Or the cause of your problem?